# How to get Webpack to correctly compile my JS and CSS files after npm updates

Tags: docker, webpack, babeljs, uglifyjs

After moving to new laptop, I have updated many node packages and this has broken my webpack. It is not building my CSS and JS files correctly. I am running a local development environment on my laptop and building a docker container for testing. Since webpack is one of the updated packages, there are some outdated plugins in my webpack config like 'extract-text-webpack-plugin' and 'CommonsChunkPlugin'. I need a little help from someone who understand this better than I do.

I have spent a couple of days trying to figure out how to modify this but need a little help. It is currently building the files (bundle.css, vendor.css, bundle.js, and vendor.js) but the CSS files are not minified and the JS files I not sure what I getting, but they have all sorts of calls to node_module files (which should be excluded) and are not minifies.

Original webpack.config.js

```
const
    Path = require('path'),
    Webpack = require('webpack'),
    ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin'),

    // Create multiple instances
    extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('styles-vendor.css'),
    extractSCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('styles-bundle.css'),
    rootDir = Path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..'),
    srcDir = Path.resolve(rootDir, 'src'),
    isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'

const config = {
    context: srcDir,

    entry: {
        vendor: [
            "./vendor"
        ],
        bundle: [
            "./styles/root.scss",
            "./entry"
        ]
    },

    output: {
        filename: "[name].js",
        path: Path.resolve(rootDir, 'dist', 'assets'),
        publicPath: "/assets/"
    },

    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: [/node_modules/],
            use: ['babel-loader']
        },
            //  {
            //  loader: ,
            //  options: require(Path.resolve(rootDir,'.babelrc'))
            // },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|png|gif|ttf|woff|woff2|otf|svg|eot)$/,
                use: [
                    'file-loader'
                ],
            }, {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: extractCSS.extract([ 'css-loader'])
                //  [
                //  'style-loader',
                //  'css-loader'
                // ],
            }, {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: extractSCSS.extract([ 'css-loader','sass-loader'])
                // use: [
                //  'style-loader',
                //  'css-loader',
                //  'sass-loader'
                // ],
            }]

    },

    devtool: isProduction ? "source-map" : "inline-source-map",

    plugins: [
        // new Webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        //  'Promise': 'bluebird'
        // }),
        extractCSS,
        extractSCSS,
        new Webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: "vendor"
        })
    ],

    node: {
        __filename: true,
        __dirname: true
    },

    devServer: {
        contentBase: Path.resolve(srcDir),
        publicPath: "/assets/",
        port: 19000,
        host: "0.0.0.0"


    },
    watchOptions: {
        poll: 1000
    }
}

if (isProduction) {
    config.plugins.unshift(
        new Webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            sourceMap: true,
            compress: {
                warnings: true,
                drop_console: false,
            }
        })
    )
}

module.exports = config
```

Attempt to write my webpack.config.js

```
const
    Path = require('path'),
    Webpack = require('webpack'),
    //ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin'),
    MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin'),

    // Create multiple instances
    //extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('styles-vendor.css'),
    //extractSCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('styles-bundle.css'),
    extractCSS = new MiniCssExtractPlugin('styles-vendor.css');
    extractSCSS = new MiniCssExtractPlugin('styles-bundle.css');
    rootDir = Path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..'),
    srcDir = Path.resolve(rootDir, 'src'),
    isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'

const config = {
    context: srcDir,
    entry: {
        vendor: [
            "./vendor"
        ],
        bundle: [
            "./styles/root.scss",
            "./entry"
        ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[name].js",
        path: Path.resolve(rootDir, 'dist', 'assets'),
        publicPath: "/assets/"
    },

    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['babel-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|png|gif|ttf|woff|woff2|otf|svg|eot)$/,
                use: [
                    'file-loader'
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                     'css-loader'
                    ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ]
                // use: [
                //  'style-loader',
                //  'css-loader',
                //  'sass-loader'
                // ],
            }
        ]

    },

    devtool: isProduction ? "source-map" : "inline-source-map",
    mode: isProduction ? "production" : "development",
    plugins: [
        // new Webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        //  'Promise': 'bluebird'
        // }),
        extractCSS,
        extractSCSS,
        //new Webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        //  name: "vendor"
        //})
    ],

    node: {
        __filename: true,
        __dirname: true
    },

    devServer: {
        contentBase: Path.resolve(srcDir),
        publicPath: "/assets/",

        port: 19000,
        host: "0.0.0.0"


    },
    watchOptions: {
        poll: 1000
    }
}

if (isProduction) {
    config.plugins.unshift(
        new Webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            sourceMap: true,
            compress: {
                warnings: true,
                drop_console: false,
            }
        })
    )
}

module.exports = config
```

One interesting thing is the original config used to output /assets/styles-bundle.css and now just outputs /assets/bundle.css. Thats not the biggest issue, but wondering if I changed something to cause that.

I also found it interesting that the original file has a test for jsx, but my files are actually '.js'. Has me a little confused as you how this is/was even finding the JS files.

Any direction and assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I guess you will need to spend some time studying the documentation of the version you are currently using.

Comment: Spent two days. That’s why I’m asking for help. Thanks.